# Replacing word if condition is met

Tags: powershell

I want to replace the word "XRF " with "CALC" at column 27 to 30 in line 5  of file attached, if all values in column named "Total" are 99.95 like in the file attached.

[image: Example Source File]

```bsh
$InFolder = "C:\sif\"
$OutFolder = "C:\Edited\"
$files = Get-ChildItem $InFolder -Recurse -Include *.sif
foreach ($file in $files) {
  $OutFile = $OutFolder + $file.BaseName + "_FeC.sif"
  $OutFile
  $Lines = Get-Content $file
  $Fe_C = "Y"
  foreach ($Line in $Lines) {
    while ($Fe_C -ne "N") {
      if ($Line.ReadCount -ge 8) {
        if (($line.Split(" ")) -eq "99.95") {
          $Fe_C = "Y"
        } else {
          $Fe_C = "N"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post code and data as *text* rather than images

Comment: Okay, and what have you tried? This question is currently just asking us to write your code for you and StackOverflow is not a code writing resource.

Comment: Sorry. Here is my script. it stops while checking 99.95 at last column. I am not sure how to get the last column using split.

Comment: $InFolder = "C:\sif\"
$OutFolder = "C:\Edited\"
$files = Get-ChildItem $InFolder -recurse -Include *.sif
foreach ($file in $files){
$OutFile = $OutFolder + $file.BaseName +"_FeC.sif"
$OutFile
    $Lines = Get-Content $file
        $Fe_C = "Y"
        foreach ($Line in $Lines)
        {While ($Fe_C -ne "N")
              {if ($Line.ReadCount -ge 8)
                {if ( ($line.Split("    ")) -eq "99.95")
                      {$Fe_C = "Y"}
                      else
                      {$Fe_C = "N"}
                 }    
     }                                   
 }}

Comment: As I cannot post my whole script, I just cut the part of it where script stops. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if none of the data lines has a value other than 99.95 in data column 15, and if so replace the first occurrence of "XRF" in line 5 with "CALC".

To do that replace this:

```
$Lines = Get-Content $file
$Fe_C = "Y"
foreach ($Line in $Lines) {
  ...
}
```

with this:

```
$Lines = Get-Content $file
$different = [bool]($Lines |
             Select-Object -Skip 7 |
             Where-Object { $_ } |
             Where-Object { ($_ -split '\s+')[15] -ne '99.95' })
if (-not $different) {
  $Lines[4] = $Lines[4] -replace 'XRF (.*)', 'CALC$1'
}
Set-Content -Path $file -Value $Lines
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions and assuming the Total column is the last:

```
if (($lines[7..($lines.count-1)] -notmatch '\s99\.95\s*$|^\s*$').count -eq 0) {
    $lines[4] = ([regex]'XRF').replace($lines[4], 'CALC', 1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar and wOxxOm. Both solutions work what I am expecting. I have learnt using bool and CALC. Appreciated. Regards. Maw